# How to have non-FQDN addresses turned to FQDN when Accessing SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, url, alternate-access-mapping, dns

I have users who have short-cuts, favorites and other links that are non-FQDN.

SharePoint opens up with these non-FQDN links and keeps using them. Our SharePoint servers are configured to use the FQDN addresses, therefore some features of SharePoint don't work with these non-FQDN addresses.

Alternative access mappings for the site have the FQDN and the non-FQDN. You can type into an internet browser window the address non-FQDN and it will be changed to `http://sharepointsite.domain.com`, but when someone uses a shortcut, favorite, and other links that are non-FQDN, the `domain.com` is not added. SharePoint does not like this.

What can I do so all addresses are FQDN used by SharePoint no matter?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check.

1. as you mentioned, you have Non-FQDN & FQDN in the AAM, are all in the same zone and redirect to FQDN? If not then add non-fqdn into the default zone or in the same zone where you have FQDN....you can do this via Add internal URL.
2. AAM having their limitation, if user type just `http://sharepointsite` then it will redirect to `http://sharepointsite.domain.com` but if User type `http//sharepointsite/pages/default.aspx` then it will not redirect to FQDN. SO if user book mark the complete url then you have to go for the other options.
3. You have to use the URL redirect / rewrite  method. check this KB for supported method http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415/en-us

Also read this blog to understand the AAM.
http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/

---

This worked in my 2013 environment.
Create two Alternate Access Mappings. One for http://sharepointname.domain.com as the Intranet Zone and the other http://sharepointname as the Custom Zone.
Now users get the same content from either http://sharepointname/subiste/page or http://sharepointname.domain.com/subiste/page

---

Comment: For the AAM, I have the following

    Internal URL
    http://xxx
    http://xxx.domain.com

    Zone:  Default

    Public URL Zone
    http://xxx.domain.com

     I tried adding http://xxx as default Internal URL

But SharePoint says its already added, The IncomingUrl is already present in the collection.

When a user types in http://xxx then the resolves to a FQDN, so this behavior is already happening.  However, it does not change the address to a FQDN if its full address that lists other directories and the page. 

I will review the links you provided.

Thank you.

Comment: if it already redirecting the xxx and only failed when url contains path till list/lib then only solution is re write url.